# How to create a Google BigQuery service account with access to a single dataset?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, google-bigquery

Is there any way of granting readonly access to a specific BigQuery Dataset to a given Client ID ?

I've tried using a service account, but this gives full access to all datasets.

Also tried creating a service account from a different application, and added the email address generated together with the certificate to the BigQuery > Some Dataset > Share Dataset > Can view, but this always results in a 403 "Access not Configured" error.

I'm using the server to server flow described in the documentation :

```
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

# REPLACE WITH YOUR Project ID
PROJECT_NUMBER = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'
# REPLACE WITH THE SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL FROM GOOGLE DEV CONSOLE
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

f = file('key.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    key,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly')

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('bigquery', 'v2')
tables = service.tables()
response = tables.list(projectId=PROJECT_NUMBER, datasetId='SomeDataset').execute(http)

print(response)
```

I'm basically trying to provide readonly access to an external server based application to a single dataset.

Comment: Did you turn on the BigQuery api on the newly created application?

Comment: Thanks ! This actually made the trick.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Fh, it is required to activate the BigQuery API in the Google Account where the service account is created, regardless of the fact that it will be querying a BigQuery endpoint bound to a different application ID.